# React Native stored array data with asyncstorage returns nothing

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build a lunch picker app that allows user to add their own menu. I want to save user data into array by using AsyncStorage. However, my value returns nothing even though the array has values. Below is my code.

```
    //Main screen
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  //initial
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
      myMenu: '????',
      menutext: '',
      randomArray: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      visibility: false,
    };
  }

  _loadMenu = async () => {
     try{
       const loadMenu = await AsyncStorage.getItem("menuInStorage")
       const parsedLoadMenu = JSON.parse(loadMenu)
       const myReturn = [...this.state.randomArray, parsedLoadMenu]
       this.setState({randomArray: myReturn})

     }
     catch(err){
       alert(err)
     }

   }

  //get input from textinput field and add to array
  addMenu = newMenu => {
    //...
    this._saveMenu(this.state.randomArray)
  };






   _saveMenu = (saving) => {
     const saveMenu = AsyncStorage.setItem("menuInStorage", JSON.stringify(saving))
   }



  //control modal
  setModalVisibility(visible) {
    this.setState({visibility: visible});
  }


  //UI
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

        <View style={[styles.container, {flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}]}>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, fontSize: 20, paddingLeft: 15, textAlign: 'left', width: 250, borderBottomColor: '#D1D1D1', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}
            placeholder=".."
            onChangeText={menutext => this.setState({ menutext })}
            value={this.state.menutext}
          />
          <Button
            title=".."
            onPress={() => this.addMenu(this.state.menutext)}
            buttonStyle={{width:100}}
            backgroundColor="#2E282A"
          />
        </View>


          <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setModalVisibility(true)}
            title=".."
            buttonStyle={{width: 150}}
            backgroundColor="#2E282A"
          />
        </View>

        <Modal
          onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ visibility: false })}
          animationType={'slide'}
          transparent={false} 
          visible={this.state.visibility}
          >

          <View style={[styles.modalContainer, {marginBottom: 100}]}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, { fontWeight: 'bold', padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#9090DA', borderBottomColor: '#5C5C8B',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,}]}>
                {'<'}List will be here{'>'}
            </Text>
            <ScrollView style={{height: "94%"}}>
              <View style={styles.row}>{this.state.randomArray}</View>

            </ScrollView>
            <Button
                buttonStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 5}}
                backgroundColor="#2E282A"
                onPress={() => this.setModalVisibility(!this.state.visibility)}
                title="Close"
            />
          </View>
        </Modal>

      </View>
    );  
  }

}
```

How the app supposed to work is, when user clicks a button, the modal shows all data in array called 'randomArray'. After user added their custom text, it should be added at the end of the randomArray. I want to save this data to the disk and load from the disk when the app is launched. At this moment, I can load array data, but it doesn't keep user data. My current code returns nothing. I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: update your addMenu method 




addMenu = newMenu => {
    //...
    this._saveMenu(this.state.randomArray)
  };


because your saveMenu() did not called

Comment: Also use aync and await while storing data into asyncstorage.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code to call _saveMenu function and moved _loadMenu to the top. However, still the data aren't saved when I kill the app and re-launch.T.T

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the logic in `_loadMenu` is slightly incorrect on this line:

```
const myReturn = [...this.state.randomArray, parsedLoadMenu]
```

If I understand correctly, you're expecting `parsedLoadMenu` to be a value of type `Array`. The line above will basically append the value `parsedLoadMenu` to the resulting array stored in `myReturn` - in the case of your code, this will mean the last item of `myReturn` will be an array, which would be incorrect from what I see in your code. Consider updating this line as shown:

```
/* 
Add ... before parsedLoadMenu to concatenate the two arrays in myReturn
*/
const myReturn = [...this.state.randomArray, ...parsedLoadMenu]
```

By adding the `...` as shown, this causes the two arrays `this.state.randomArray` and `parsedLoadMenu` to be concatenated together in `myReturn`. It would also be worth checking the parse result from `JSON.parse()` to ensure that it is an array before attempting this concatenation:

```
_loadMenu = async () => {
     try{
       const loadMenu = await AsyncStorage.getItem("menuInStorage")
       let parsedLoadMenu = JSON.parse(loadMenu)

       /* 
       Consider an additional check here to ensure the loaded data is of
       correct Array type before proceeding with concatenation
       */
       if(!Array.isArray(parsedLoadMenu)) {
           parsedLoadMenu = [];
       }

       /* Concatenate the two arrays and store result in component state */
       const myReturn = [...this.state.randomArray, ...parsedLoadMenu]
       this.setState({randomArray: myReturn})

     }
     catch(err){
       alert(err)
     }    
   }
```

Also, consider revising the `addMenu` logic, so that the entire array of menu items in your is persisted to `AsyncStorage` rather than the newly added menu item only, as you are currently doing:

```
addMenu = (newMenu) => {

    /* 
    Persist current randomArray with newMenu item appended 
    */
    this._saveMenu([...this.state.randomArray, newMenu])
};
```

Hope this helps!